# Put Search and Menu Bar in the Foreground, Above Animated Header

Tags: html, css

Help get the Search Bar and Menu in the foreground. I tried the Z-index and that has not worked. I have a negative margin on the search bar to put it in the top part of the website. It's hidden behind the solar system image.

http://wearethenewmedia.com/indextrial.html

Also, see original at WeAreTheNewMedia.com

It's too much code to post in here.

Thanks!!

We're also trying to implement this Sidebar with our Menu button.
Link: http://wearethenewmedia.com/menu/index.html

Comment: Please put your code, use better grammar, and explain what you are looking for. If it's "too much code" then you have to narrow down the problem or no one can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code it's hard to evaluate or make any suggestions. You should be able to use `position: fixed;` on whatever container the nav is in to attach it to the top. This will put it on the top of the solar system image. If you don't want it to appear until after, just use jquery to make it fade in once you pass the solar system image.

Comment: It's already a fixed header as you scroll past it.The reason i can't post all the code is because

Comment: It's already a fixed header as you scroll past it.   The reason I can't post all the code is because these is multiple css and a js that is in conflict possibly.

Comment: i don't want to fade it in :)